# Database: Check data type by python using cx_oracle

Tags: python, sql, database, cx-oracle

For example, if I have following code:

```
#people( sin, name, height,weight,eyecolor, haircolor,addr,gender,birthday )
sin = input("sin ---->")  
gender = input("gender ---->")
```

I need check whether 'sin' is an integer or say, a 'INT' in oracle data type.

And whether gender is f or m.

How can I do this? Is there any different way from:

```
while gender != 'f' or gender != 'm':
    gender = input("gender ---->")
```

The two attributes above will be insert into my database by SQL statement

I am using cx_Oracle

Comment: Actually I want to get a general way suitable for all the data types since there are also some other data types like blob and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use isinstance()?

`isinstance(sin, int)` will eval to true or false.
`isinstance(object_instance, object_type)` might work for the other objects you want to evaluate as well.

Your checking of 'f' or 'm' is a bit different since you're comparing data rather than type.  Not sure if you can get around that way of checking data.

Hope that helps.